# How to compare two properties of a class

Tags: java, comparable

There is a class `Movie` which has two properties, `id` and `type`.

```
static class Movie implements Comparable<Movie> {
    Integer id;
    Type type;

    Movie(Integer id, Type type) {
        this.id = id;
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(final Movie other) {
        return 0;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Type getType() {
        return type;
    }
}

enum Type {
    TYPE_A,
    TYPE_B
}
```

Let's say that this is the input:

```
// MOVIE_ID  MOVIE_TYPE
// 1         TYPE_A
// 2         TYPE_B
// 3         TYPE_A
// 4         TYPE_B
```

and the output I want to achieve is this:

```
// MOVIE_ID  MOVIE_TYPE
// 1         TYPE_A
// 3         TYPE_A
// 2         TYPE_B
// 4         TYPE_B
```

Also I want to be sure that null is greater. Are there any libraries or do I need to implement it by my own, if so, what's the best way to achieve that?

Comment: those two properties aren't of the same type, not even hierarchical, so you can't "compare" them. you can sort them by type, for instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to compare by type first, and then by ID? In that case, you need some `compareTo` logic like this:

```
if (type != other.type) {
    return type.compareTo(other.type);
} else {
    return id.compareTo(other.id);
}
```

To account for `null`, you could add more `if`s.